# Permissible Electrostatic Potential

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, mathematical-physics

Let us consider a $1D$ real function $V(x)$. When is this a classical electrostatic potential?

My take on the problem:

1. $V(x)$ must be differentiable everywhere. In fact, we should be able to differentiate it $n$ times.
2. $V(x)$ should vanish at $\pm \infty$.

I think these are necessary and sufficient conditions. Is this right? How do I deal with discrete charge distributions, where the potential is not differentiable at the points where the charges are present?

Comment: Can you strictly define what is a classical electrostatic potential?

Comment: @AndreasMastronikolis a physical potential that obeys poisson's equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that most conditions can be seen from the Poisson equation:
$$
\frac{d^2 V(x)}{dx^2} = -\rho(x).
$$
Thus, it should be differentiable everywhere except a few singular points. One often bypasses this issue by using generalized functions (delta-function and Heaviside step function).

However, there is no requirement that the potential vanishes in infinity. For example, the potential corresponding to a constant electric field of magnitude $E$ is
$$
V(x) = - Ex
$$

Comment: Aren't you missing a negative sign in Poisson's Equation? (oh, and an $\epsilon_0$...)

Comment: @Philip Thanks. Fixed.

Comment: Obviously, E cannot be constant over an infinite range.

Comment: @my2cts I think the question is about the mathematical constraints. But physically - yes, E cannot be constant over an infinite range.